# Lawn Mower Headlights-only one headlight running

Tags: wiring

I am in process of installing some led headlights on a ztr mower. The wiring diagram for headlights is below. The left headlight(which is actually my right headlight because of location of switch) lights up fine. However, the other headlight(left in my case-one nearest switch) will not light up. I had a few questions.
1. It seems to me that I am having an issue with  terminals not being crimped right/connected snug or possibility that their is issue with led bulbs being damaged. I did drop one of the lights a few inches from off the ground by accident,but I am not sure which it was.The lights are enclosed in metal frame. Is there any other areas I need to look at for causing the problem?

2. In the instructions, they call a particular terminal a y connector. Isnt that same as female bullet connector?
3. When I did turn lights on, I could hear a very low sounding humming sound. What may be causing this?[image]

Comment: What happens if you switch the bulbs?

Comment: Do you mean replace bulbs in light not working? I haven't had a chance to do that or if the light is made for lights to be replaced(set of 9 led lights per fixture). I did remove connection to light that came on leaving other one connected and still no luck there.

Comment: You have 2 of the things, whatever they are, right?  Switch them and see if the problem moves.